# Problem with independent sigma algebras and joint sigma algebras

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

The problem is:

> Suppose that $(\Omega;\mathcal{F};\mathbf{P})$ is a complete probability space and $\mathcal{G}, \mathcal{G'}, \mathcal{H}$ be sub $\sigma$-algebras of $\mathcal{F}$ such that $\mathcal{G} \subseteq \mathcal{G'}$; $\mathcal{G'}$ is independent of $\mathcal{H}$; $\mathcal{G} \vee \mathcal{H} = \mathcal{G'} \vee \mathcal{H}$. Then $\mathcal{G} = \mathcal{G'}$.

where the joint of two $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{A} \vee \mathcal{B}$ is defined to be the smallest $\sigma$-algebra generated by $A \cap B$ with $A \in \mathcal{A}$ and $B \in \mathcal{B}$.

I have no way to approach this kind of question. The problem I find is to go from fuzzy thing (probability space) to absolute thing (equality). My intuition is that somehow one can "approximate" a sub-$\sigma$-algebra using the measure; thereby, for any $E \in \mathcal{G'}$, we can use the given assumptions to deduce that something like $\chi_E$ is $\mathcal{G}$-measurable and hence is in $\mathcal{G}$. But I have no way to make this precise.

On the other hand, for specific instance of $\mathcal{H}$ such as $\mathcal{H} = \{\emptyset, \Omega\}$, we derive directly that the joint $\mathcal{G} \vee \mathcal{H} = \mathcal{G}$ and $\mathcal{G'} \vee \mathcal{H} = \mathcal{G'}$ and so get equality from the assumption. And there is nothing to do with the measure itself.

Can anyone give me some hint?

Comment: I'd like to look into this but I DK what it means for two sigma-algebras to be independent.

Comment: @user254665 Two sub-$\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ are said to be independent if $\mathbf{P}(A \cap B) = \mathbf{P}(A) \mathbf{P}(B)$ for any $A \in \mathcal{A}$ and $B \in \mathcal{B}$.